# how to update one record in Mogodb using PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I am finding a record by using this piece of code

> 1:) This statement find a record successfully.

`$collection->findOne(array("email" => $email));`

> 2:) Now i want to update a record where _id="5725301d76dc3a0809000029" i use this piece of code but its show me syntax error

```
$collection->update(array({ "_id" : ObjectId("5725301d76dc3a0809000029")}, {$set:{'title':'New MongoDB Tutorial'}}));
```

> please Guide me how to update a record. If my syntax is Wrong so tel me the correct syntax. my query is .. 
>   **UPDATE userss SET title='My Title' WHERE _id=ObjectId("5725301d76dc3a0809000029");**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```html
$collection->update
(
 array('_id' =>  new MongoId('5725301d76dc3a0809000029')),
 array('$set' => array( 'title' => 'My Title' ))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

> The right syntax is given below...
>   It works fine :)

```
$collection = $this->mongo_db->db->selectCollection('surfinme');
$data = array('sitename'=> 'surfinme', 'title' => 'Mongodb');
$collection->update(array('_id' => new MongoId($uniqueId)), array('$set' => $data),array("upsert" => false));
```

Comment: That is just what @Jose proposed as answer.

Comment: yup i see this on a web page  [please have a look](http://www.surfinme.com/basic-mongodb-queries-with-codeigniter-php/)